# Bootgrid and &nbsp;

Tags: jquery, jquery-bootgrid

Using BootGrid, when I pull a blank field from mysql , it displays   - How do I remove this?

I populate the modal form as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT debt_master.id, debt_master

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data[] = $row;
}

$json_data = array(
    "current"            => intval($params['current']), 
    "rowCount"            => 10,            
    "total"    => intval($qtot->num_rows),
    "rows"            => $data   // total data array
    );

return $json_data;
```

The result is supposed to be blank with no spaces shown

Comment: Could you provide some more background? Is the code you posted server side php? Do you mean jQuery Bootgrid, when you say BootGrid? You could add some more tags to your questions, to clarify this (e.g. jquery-bootgrid, javascirpt, php)

Comment: Yes Jquery Bootgrid - yes server side php. It pulls an array from the database, I manage to search the array and it definately does not show &nbsp; . This means its on the actual form itself.